# how to rewrite a looping code with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a code

```
for (i in 1:length(datasets)) assign(datasets[i], read.csv(paste0(file_dir,datasets[i]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE))
```

I want to rewrite it with `lapply`. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
datasetList <- lapply(datasets, function(datasetname) {
  read.csv(paste0(file_dir,datasetname),stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
}
```

will give you a list of datasets. You can access the `i`-th dataset by calling `datasetList[[i]]`

If you want to access the datasets by their names, just name the list via

```
datasetList <- setNames(datasetList,datasets)
```

and you can access a dataset called "datasetXXX" via `datasetList$datasetXXX` or  `datasetList[[datasetXXX]]`

Comment: Is it possible to keep the dataset name as is in the list. calling[i] is not applicable for my case as I have 100+ data

Comment: Sorry for the late respnse, I updated my answer for named access to the datasets.

Comment: will it possible to combine `datasetList <- setNames(datasetList,datasets)` into  `datasetList <- lapply(datasets, function(datasetname) {
  read.csv(paste0(file_dir,datasetname),stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
}`?

Comment: Yes, you can just write `setNames(lapply(datasets,...),datasets)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(readr)
datasetList <- map(datasets, ~ read_csv(file.path(file_dir, .x)))
names(datasetList) <- datasets
```

Comment: Thanks. This one yards the same results lapply. we lost the data names while we read in. Is it a way to keep the original data name as object name, so we can call datasetList[[ae]] instead of datasetList[[1]]?

Comment: @Stataq you can assign the names with `names(datasetlist) <- datasets`

Comment: Is it possible to do the naming in the same map() ?

Comment: @Stataq You want to named the `list` elements, you can use `map(setNames(datasets, datasets),  ~read_csv(file.path(file_dir, .x)))`

Comment: When we use `map()`, we pass `setNames(datasets, datasets)` through the `read_CSV`?  or we read_CSV first, then setNames? The codes work. I am just confused about the order of how theses pass through.

Comment: @Stataq Either way you can do that.  In the code I showed, it is just passing a named vector.  You can also do the `setNames` at the end output i.e. `setNames(map(datasets, read_csv(file.path(file_dir, .x))), datasets)`

Comment: Why this one `datasets<- map(setNames(datasets, datasets),  ~read_csv(file.path(file_dir, .x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE))` did not work. Where can we add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE`

Comment: @Stataq There is no need as it is by default FALSE as the default usage options are `read_csv(file, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL,
  locale = default_locale(), na = c("", "NA"), quoted_na = TRUE,
  quote = "\"", comment = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0,
  n_max = Inf, guess_max = min(1000, n_max),
  progress = show_progress(), skip_empty_rows = TRUE)`

Comment: what if I wan t`header=FALSE`, where should I put it in the codes?

Comment: @Stataq There is a `col_names` argument which is TRUE by default, and it can changed